# Single VS Code shortcut for start/restart

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, vscode-debugger

The default VS Code shortcuts seem to be:

- F5: start
- Shift-F5: stop
- F8: continue (if paused)
- Shift-F8: restart

The thing I most often want to do is "take any changes into account and run", which means three different things depending on state:

- if not running: F5
- if running: Shift-F8 (or Shift-F5, F5)
- if paused: Shift-F8 (or Shift-F5, F5)

Is there a way to configure it so that one key combination will start (if not running) or restart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, it seems to be as simple as: Set "F5" as the shortcut for "Debug: Restart" (as well as for "Debug: Start"). The When setting of "inDebugMode" means VS Code knows to perform a restart rather than a start.