# How to automatically terminate last instance when running or debugging in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Coming from Eclipse, I am very used to the option to terminate the possible old and running instance of the code I'm working on. With VS Code, I instead have to select the console, press `Ctrl+C`, wait for the process to end and only then can I launch a new instance via `Ctrl+F5` (same for debug/regular `F5`).

I was surprised to find no such option in VS Code, am I missing something or is this feature simply not supported ? If this is possible to configure somehow, how would I go about it ? Multiple tags because I'm not sure which part of VS Code would be responsible here. I am specifically developing in Java, if that is relevant.

Comment: Are you stopping the same debug session or possibly a different one?

Comment: I am asking how to automatically stop the last/currently running session. I am not myself stopping anything other than manually.

Comment: I am voting to close my own question as the question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254357/single-vs-code-shortcut-for-start-restart essentially answers this one. I originally did not find the referenced question because I was thinking about an option to the `Run/Debug` functionality instead of the approach the other question took